# Excel Returns False Value For Comparing Two Exact Cells

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a long list of numbers stored in excel and I need to compare them with another file in order to extract corresponding data.
But the thing the numbers do not match with even their exact value!
I tried changing the cell`s format or even copy and paste values into another file but nothing worked!

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! Have you already tried `=IF(ROUND(VALUE(<this_cell>);6)=ROUND(VALUE(<another_cell>);6))` ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hello, please read https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask If you're talking about comparing values, not even showing values you're comparing is not the way to go.

Comment: Please share us with more details, such as the sample, the results that you need. Thx ~

Answer (score 0):

Making a computer compare values may turn up as tricky.

The problem comes from e.g. the fact that `1/10` i.e. `0.1` cannot be represented EXACTLY using binary numbers.
*(compare to 1/3 or 1/7 for decimal numbers, that you're used to)*

Another fact is that computers looks at ALL decimals, e.g. what is displayed as `1.25` may well have a single 1 in the 16:th decimal; this isn't automatically ignored.
*i.e. the ACTUAL value is `1.2500000000000001`*

And the story goes on like that...

What @johnSUN tells, is the way to go
`=IF(ROUND(VALUE(<this_cell>);6)=ROUND(VALUE(<another_cell>);6);1;0)`
will tell the truth when the values are very close.